# Trying to switch which photo pops up depending on button clicked Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uiimageview

I am making an app that will display a random quote from a stoic philosopher.  Right now, I am stuck on trying to make the correct picture pop up.  (User clicks on a Button with the philosopher's name on it, and then a new view pops up with an image of the philosopher and a random quote by him).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var allQuotes = [String]()
    var pictures = [String]()
    
    @IBOutlet var Epictetus: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Seneca: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var MarcusAurelius: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        // Create a constant fm and assign it the value returned by FileManager.default (built in system type)
        
        let fm = FileManager.default
        
        //  Declares a new constant called path that sets the resource path of ours apps buddle.
        //  A bundle is a directory containing our compiled program and all our assets
        
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        
        // items array will be a constant collection of the names of all the files found in the directory of our app
        
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
        
        // create a loop to go through all of our items...
        
        for item in items {
            if item.hasSuffix("jpg"){
                pictures.append(item)
            }
        }
        
        print(pictures)
        
        title = "Stoicism"
        
        if let stoicQuotesURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "quotes", withExtension: "txt"){
            if let stoicQuotes = try? String(contentsOf: stoicQuotesURL) {
                allQuotes = stoicQuotes.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 0 {
            if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Picture") as? PictureViewController {
                vc.selectedImage = pictures[0]
                navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
        else if sender.tag == 1 {
            if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Picture") as? PictureViewController {
                vc.selectedImage = pictures[1]
                navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
        else if sender.tag == 2 {
            if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Picture") as? PictureViewController {
                vc.selectedImage = pictures[2]
                navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

That's the code for my main viewController.

```
import UIKit

class PictureViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet var picture: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    var selectedImage: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        if let imageToLoad = selectedImage {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageToLoad)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        // doing it for the parent class
        
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // if its a nav Cont then it will hide bars on tap...
    }
    
    // now make sure it turns off when you go back to the main screen
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

That's the code for the viewController that has the imageView.  Right now, the image that's popping up is always the preset (Marcus Aurelius), even though my code looks correct to me.  Obviously it isn't (also, I've already debugged and ensured through print statements that the jpg files add to the pictures array correctly).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you assign the correct `tag`s to your buttons?
Also, I would highly suggest you move away from what you have now, and use a tableView, because I assume you have a list of items which you click and open a new viewController. What you have now is not scalable. What if you have 200 items on the screen? Will you go and manually assign the `tag` for each button? Also, your screen will be very heavy and the app will consume too much memory and CPU.

Comment: Where is the SwiftUI in this question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code is really silly:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Picture") as? PictureViewController {
            vc.selectedImage = pictures[0]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
    else if sender.tag == 1 {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Picture") as? PictureViewController {
            vc.selectedImage = pictures[1]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
    else if sender.tag == 2 {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Picture") as? PictureViewController {
            vc.selectedImage = pictures[2]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Do you see that everything in those lines is identical except for the numbers? So make the number a variable:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Picture") as? PictureViewController {
        print(sender.tag)
        vc.selectedImage = pictures[sender.tag]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

See how much shorter and clearer that is? Okay, I've also added a `print` statement. This will print the tag to the console. You need to make sure that your buttons do have the right tags. If they do, your code should work.